# Package manager tells me I installed postgresql-9.6, but when I login I still see version 9.3

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, postgresql

I’m using Ubuntu 14.04.  I’m trying to upgrade to a PostGres 9.6 server and was following directions [here](https://raonyguimaraes.com/how-to-install-postgresql-9-6-on-ubuntudebianlinux-mint/).  When I get to the final step about installing the package, it tells me it is about to install it, but then nothing seems to happen:

```
root@remotebox:~# apt-get install postgresql-9.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  postgresql-9.6
Suggested packages:
  locales-all
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 117 not upgraded.
```

When I reboot my machine (via `sudo reboot now`) and login, I still see the 9.3 server

```
postgres@remotebox:~$ psql
psql (9.6.0, server 9.3.11)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

Interestingly, then I run `apt-cache`, it seems like its installed:

```
postgres@remotebox:~$ apt-cache policy postgresql-9.6
postgresql-9.6:
  Installed: 9.6.0-1.pgdg14.04+1
  Candidate: 9.6.0-1.pgdg16.04+1
  Version table:
     9.6.0-1.pgdg16.04+1 0
        500 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ xenial-pgdg/main amd64 Packages
 *** 9.6.0-1.pgdg14.04+1 0
        500 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Do I need to do something else to install/launch the 9.6 server?

Comment: Do you have *both* `postgresql-9.3` and `postgresql-9.6` installed?  The one doesn't supersede the other, so usually they both get installed, please confirm if this is the case.

Comment: Ah you are wise.  I do indeed have 9.3 installed.  I thought putting in 9.6 would replace 9.3 but I guess I have to uninstall 9.3.

Comment: I had this same problem. just remove the 9.3

Comment: You have to move your data first.  Then uninstall 9.3.

Comment: Removing 9.3 outright landed me in a world of pain.  Upgrading worked though, as I followed this guy's guide -- https://blog.chaps.io/2016/02/08/upgrading-postgresql-from-9-4-to-9-5-on-ubuntu-15-10.html .